# родительный падеж and дательный падеж how to choose мне or мня?

Tags: грамматика

I start to studied Russian one month ago. My teacher show me how to use родительный падеж and дательный падеж but i really don't understand the differences.

For example if I want to say:
He give me a rose - он подарил мне розу 
why I use мне and not м**Е**ня ?

кому or кого meaning always "To Whom?" so how can I understand the difference between родительный падеж and дательный падеж if the question is always same and also the translation of мне / м**Е**ня?

Thanks

[image: Rules]

Comment: because there's no such word as **мня**, there's word **меня** which is Genitive of **я**, but the verb **давать** doesn't govern Genitive case, it governs Dative and Accusative ***давать кому? что?***... if you want to know why, this is rather a question about linguistics and logic of a language, try to compare with Italian and maybe you'll be able to grasp the logic

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, In Italian we always use same word as you can see from my Italian screenshot :) , so no difference for us. 
How Russian can understand in a phrase like that "он подарил мне розу" to use мне and not меня ?

Comment: if that's the case and Italian is no help, i guess it must just be memorized or fall back on English, or any other language you're familiar with, in English the verb **to give** always requires the preposition **to** (-> **to give to**) and the name of the case Дательный (Dative) in Russian derives from the same root as the word давать (to give), so when a verb means transfer of something between two objects it usually governs Dative case, but basically the cases need to be learned along with verbs

Comment: Just memorize that the addressee,  who is happy to receive your rose will be in the Dative кому? мне

Comment: **кому?** and **кого?** aren't translated identically into English - **кому?** is **to/at whom?** but **кого?** is **(of) whom/whose**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dative case (дательный падеж) is used for the addressee in 'give':

- Он дал **мне** книгу. = Он дал книгу **мне**.
- He gave **me** the book. = He gave the book **to me**.
- **Mi** ha dato il libro. = Lui ha dato il libro **a me**.

The Accusative case (винительный падеж) is used for the direct object of the action:

- Он дал мне **книгу**. (`книгу` is the Accusative of `книга`, book)
- Он спросил **меня**. (`меня` is the Accusative of `я`, I)

The Genitive case (родительный падеж) often appears after prepositions like **без, у, от**:

- Иди без **меня**. - Go without me.
- У **меня** есть книга. - I have a book.

What complicates matters a bit, **меня** can be either Genitive or Accusative, depending on context. In "Он спросил меня" it's Accusative, not Genitive. Your teacher is mistaken.